# Optimization Problems which very deep local minima

Tags: optimization, combinatorics

I am looking for combinatorial optimization problems which have very deep local minima.

So I am searching for the global optimum (which is not unique).

Are there some games or problems you know which have this behavior? A problem without a reward function for each step.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question you're asking. Nonetheless, you may want to look into pseudoknot prediction and finding the ground state of a spin glass, as two examples of combinatorial optimisation problems with deep local minima.

Comment: I too find it hard to understand what you're asking.  It seems your situation boils down to "I need to find the global optimum", and if so, I'm not sure there's a lot to say.  It's hard to say without knowing what your objective function is.  I think one relevant issue is whether local information on the objective function helps point you in the right direction for the global optimum or not; if it doesn't, life might get difficult.

Comment: I reformulated my question, thanks for these examples